# How to reset the timer properly in react js

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class HeartBeat extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timeRemaining: 15 * 60,
      timeBeforeWarning: (15 * 60) - 300,
      showWarning: false,
      showError: false,
    };

    this.currentTick = 0;
    this.intervalId  = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.updateTick.bind(this), 6000)
  }

  updateTick() {
    if (this.currentTick < 600) {
      this.currentTick += 60;
    } else if (this.currentTick > 540 && this.currentTick < 900) {
      if (!this.state.showWarning) {
        this.setState({
          showWarning: true,
        });
      }

      this.currentTick += 60;
    } else if (this.currentTick === 900) {
      this.setState({
        showWarning: false,
        showError: true,
      });

      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }

    console.log(this.currentTick);
  }

  resetTimmer() {
    this.intervalId = 0;

    this.setState({
      showWarning: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.showWarning) {
      return (
        <div className="alert alert-warning">Your session is about to expire in 5 minutes <a href="#" onClick={this.resetTimmer.bind(this)}>Click me to stay logged in</a></div>
      )
    }

    if (this.state.showError) {
      return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger">Your session expired.</div>
      )
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

The idea here is simple: Every 6 seconds increment the `currentTick` by 60. if that value is greater then 540 but less then 900 then show a warning. If its 900, show an error. If they click on the link in the warning the timer should be reset and we should start all over again.

### Issues:

- I am doing `this.intervalId = 0` in the onClick function, which doesn't work. Because it just keep incrementing the existing value. I did try `clearInterval(this.intervalId)` but that stopped the timer completely. I just want to reset the timer.

  - The only time I want to stop the timer is if their session actually times out.
- The warning seems to show only when the `currentTick` is 660, which is not whats suppose to happen. Not sure  how to fix that.

### The goal:

When the warning shows, we do an ajax call to the server to just essentially ping it to keep the session alive (I use Laravel as the back end) When a successful 200 comes back then we reset the timer. (I know how to do the ajax call, its just for now I have it as a simple event handler to just "reset the timer")

**Note:** I have set the timer to `setInterval(this.updateTick.bind(this), 6000)` instead of `60000` for testing purposes. Once I know this works it will be set to 60000.

Can some one tell me how to reset the timer such that it starts all over again and if I have placed the logic for the timer in the right place?

Comment: I think you confused this.intervalId which is the number you need to stop / clear the interval and this.currentTick which is the value you increment and you want to reset. Also I think this is the only state you need everything else can be derifed from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a basic interval which updates the state every minute:

```
import React from 'react'

class Counter extends React.Component{
    state = {
        timer:  0
    }

    tick = null

    onTick = () => this.setState({timer : this.state.timer + 60})

    componentDidMount(){
        this.tick = setInterval(this.onTick, 60000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.tick)
    }

    render(){
        const { timer} = this.state
        return(
            <div>
                {(timer > 540 && timer <900) && 'Warning'}
                {timer > 900 && 'Error'}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the question as an opportunity to learn how `setInterval` would work with hooks. I was having some issues until I came to this post by Dan Abramov:

https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Then I created my version of the problem on CodeSandbox using the `useInterval` function proposed on the post.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ticker-liqo9

I hope it helps